# Getting error while clicking on the tab in Oracle forms application

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am getting error when clicking on one tab in Oracle forms app UI.

All other tabs are working without any issue.

Pleased suggest.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`WHEN-NEW-RECORD-INSTANCE` trigger contains code which - I presume (I must, as you didn't post any code) - references (a) table(s) in another database, but that database is *unreachable*.

Why? Because database name you provided doesn't match any of databases available to you. Usually, that's because database's alias can't be found in the TNSNAMES.ORA file. Note that this is not your "local" TNSNAMES.ORA, but the one that resides on the server. I guess you aren't using Forms 6i or lower, are you? They were client-server, so - yes, you'd copy *everything* to each client. When forms are deployed to web, you use IAS or WebLogic server.

To illustrate what's going on: that's as if you wanted to call someone on the phone, but can't find their name in a phonebook.

Therefore: make sure database is *known* and its alias is in TNSNAMES.ORA which is used by your database.

You might have several TNSNAMES.ORA files, so it depends which one will be used. I'd suggest you to maintain only one copy of the file; it should then reside in a directory (folder) on the server whose location is stored in `TNS_ADMIN` environment variable.